# scp -O (legacy protocol) option per config file?

Tags: linux, ssh, sftp, scp, manjaro

I basically have the same problem as described (and solved) here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74311661/subsystem-request-failed-on-channel-0-scp-connection-closed-macbook
This is: scp to some hosts which do not support sftp subsystem is only working if I provide the "-O" flag.

However is there a way to instead configure this behavior by default ?
E.g. by an option in `~/.ssh/config` ?
The point is: For manual use I can just use an `alias scp='scp -O'`, however this won't work in scripts and non-shell actions (such as running ansible playbooks).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you cannot use `~/.ssh/config` to solve your problem because this file is for `ssh`, not for `scp`. It's true `scp` uses `ssh` under the hood, but `-O` you want to force is an option strictly for `scp`, not for `ssh`.

You may be able to achieve an acceptable result with a wrapper script. This is the script:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
exec /usual/path/to/scp -O "$@"
```

You need to use the full path to the real `scp`. Save the script as `scp` in a directory that is earlier in your `$PATH` than all other directories in `$PATH` that hold other (in practice: the real) `scp` executable(s). Create a new directory and adjust your `$PATH` if needed. Make the script executable (`chmod +x scp`).

From now on any process that inherits your modified `$PATH` and tries to run `scp` will run the wrapper instead of the real `scp`. The wrapper will replace itself with the real `scp` that will get `-O` along with all arguments passed to the wrapper. This way `-O` will be injected automatically.

There are cases when the method cannot work:

- If a process calling `scp` uses `$PATH` which is not your modified `$PATH` then it won't find the wrapper and it will run the real `scp` directly; so `-O` won't be injected. For this reason you may want to modify `$PATH` as "globally" as possible.
- If a process calls `/usual/path/to/scp` explicitly then it will obviously call the real `scp` directly regardless of `$PATH`; so `-O` won't be injected.

A way to overcome these is:

1. Do not modify `$PATH`.
2. Move the original `scp` to a different pathname.
3. Use this pathname in the wrapper, so the wrapper execs to the real `scp` as it always should.
4. Save the wrapper as `/usual/path/to/scp`.

The downside is your OS, when being upgraded, may replace the wrapper with a new version of the real `scp`. This mishap cannot happen in the method with modified `$PATH` and unaltered `/usual/path/to/scp`.

Comment: Yes, the wrapper script was the solution I also thought of. I was hoping there is a better one, but I guess I will use this one then.

Answer (score 1):

As of the OpenSSH 9.4, the only way to select the SCP protocol with `scp` is by [`-O` switch](https://man.openbsd.org/scp#O).

No configuration file or anything else is involved.

So all solutions must be external to `scp`. Such as the alias.